# run button opens a new AVM

Tags: android, eclipse, virtual-machine

I have troubles compiling my code with eclipse. Each time I click the run button it opens a new AVM.

I am starting to get lost in here any hint or solution please?

Comment: solved the problem by restarting adb.exe everything works as before now

Answer (score 0):

The run button in eclipse is designed to launch your code, which has to be done either in the AVM or on hardware connected to your computer.  If you are wanting to build the binary without executing you go to the project menu and select Build All.  However, it is probably set by default to build automatically, which is also under the project menu.  Effectively this means the code you are writing is being built "on the fly" and errors will appear dynamically as you write your code.  Is this what you were asking?

Comment: not really sorry, i have already solved the problem, it's commented below the question. Actually the problem was that when each time i click on run it starts a new AVM without compiling or something. so i found my self with a bunch of duplicated AVMs with no compiled code.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you solved the problem!  It sounds like eclipse lost its connection to the AVM, I have that happen occasionally when trying to launch the code on my debugging device.  Cheers!